# PHP website to pass specific information only when queried

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble trying to come up with a clever way to do what I need to do.  Quite basically I have a general site, created by a custom build CMS editor, everything is fine.  What I want to have happen, is when the user is in our CMS editor, via AJAX request in the background, it will quickly query the page the user is viewing and return back special instructions depending on the data that is received.  Such as:

The contact page has some special instructions to the CMS, maybe that everything needs to have a title and a subtitle.  So those triggers are coded into the contact.php, but not displayed to the regular joe viewing the website.  No  fields.

But when the user is in our CMS, I want it to send a special request to http://www.something.com/contact.php, and contact.php will know its the CMS knocking on its door, and will reply back with special instructions.  Whethor it be JSON, or XML, something, I'm not fussy.

The real issue I am coming across is having contact.php display either versions of itself.  I can return a JSON string, but jQuery Ajax doesnt know howto handle it as there are other elements in the response.  If jQuery->Ajax could ignore the whole page and just grab the JSON that should be fine.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>blah blah</h1>
...etc
...etc
<script>var requiredSettings = {[json blah blah blha ]};</script>
<p>loreum ipsum etc..</p>
</body>
</html>
```

That is what I have to work with, how can an jQuery->Ajax request ignore all the wqrong headers and the html junk and only use the JSON.

I am very open to other methods, so long as the contact.php can remain intact and visible by users but play double duty and report back to the CMS when the CMS requests information.

The CMS and contact.php will be on different servers.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

In your PHP file you could always do:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    return jsonencode(JSON);
    die();
}

HTML site here.
```

This will return json if the page was requested with ajax, and move along to the HTML part (or whatever) if it was'nt.

Comment: Thanks adeneo, that answer is what I am leaning towards the only problem I did run into is that fact that I can only put that at the top of the PHP file.  Is there any equivliant that will allow me to put it in the middle of the PHP file?  After the headers and some HTML have already been outputted?  That's the challenge.

Comment: You can place that piece of code anywhere, but any code that is outputted before it will also be sent to the ajax function unless there are some conditions met or something, and then you would'nt receive proper JSON, but a mix, and you'd have to parse that with javascript, and that would be a lot more work than just structuring your PHP file properly.

Comment: Thanks adeneo,So ill have to look into parsing the output with java and finding what it needs.  Was hoping for a better way but ill have to code it heavy on the cms server side.  The easy option would work for me but unfortunately it won't always be me coding client sites and I can't have the coding client side break everything because the was an echo on contact.php